# $PauseOnHover start is delayed by $SlideDuration time

Tags: slider, slideshow, jssor

Nice library!

Issue: hovering mouse over  takes SlideDuration time to stop images in slider.  This is only a problem when you want the images to scroll slowly. The delay in response is noticeable and users find it somewhat irritating.

- Code in question: jssor, downloaded 20Aug14
- directory: demo-no-jquery
- file: scrolling-logo-thumbnail-slider.source

[EDIT after more investigating: regardless of speed, it seems to stop only once the edge of image reaches the $Align.  **Can this be overridden?** ]

Code is out of the box with only one Option changed: SlideDuration.

I'm guessing the hover event (or its trigger) is being swallowed by the / a function which incrementally "slides" the images and is not bubbled up?

```
var options = { // ...
                $SlideDuration: 6000 ,  
                // ... 
              };
```

Run with that. Then reset to say $SlideDuration: 500 and reload and retry. Should be immediately obvious.

Suggestions ? (And thank you for all the effort!!)

Answer (score 1):

Please set $PauseOnHover option to 4.

$PauseOnHover option values:

0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

Comment: This is just for the Scrolling-logo- thumbnail (but it might affect other scripts, I've not tried enough to know). As the edit above hints at, I'm now pretty sure the delay in stopping the logo-thumbnail scroll with $PauseOnHover enabled is a *combination* of side effects from $SlideDuration and $ParkingPosition.  Mouse hover triggers event, it continues to move until the nearest image to its parking spot reaches the $ParkingPosition... so with a slow scroll (which lets you see a logo comfortably) the delay feels inconsistent to the user [continued next comment ...]

Comment: In other words, if the image about to park is very close to it's edge, the stop feels quick. But when it's farthest away from parking,  it can feel like the delay is not even working <- which is what I thought was happening on first few tries.  Then there are all the possible combinations of times in between. So if you have a set of logo/thumbnails that are wide and slow moving - it feels quite buggy. (And of course, the users blame the website :-( for that!)  Understood there is no present work around ... can see that it might be an issue to "park" an image only part way. [Continued ...]

Comment: Maybe there's a way to catch the event, check to see if a new flag like say "$ImmediateScrollStop" is set, then just override the $ParkingPosition and stop where ever the image just happens to be ? Thanks again for the wonderful scripts!

Comment: The $PauseOnHover is to pause a slider, prevent it from auto playing from current slide to next. It works as expected. Actually, we can make the slider freeze on mouse hover, just like the behavior on mouse down. I will work on it and update you when I get it ready. Thanks again!

Comment: Great - thanks for the super fast response! >" $PauseOnHover is to pause a slider, prevent it from auto playing from current slide to next. It works as expected." Well, I'd expect it to stop immediately, instead of having to "chase after" the logo until it does stop. :))